What scales under renormalization in lattice models?
I am reading a Statistical Physics book by Kadanoff, and I am somewhat confused by how he defines the scaling renormalization. In section 12.3, he defines a renormalization scheme for the Ising model, in which one groups lattice points in blocks, so that the new blocks have lattice constant $ \lambda \alpha $. In page 255, there is a table in which he says the physical distances are invariant, in other words $\mathbf{r}\mapsto\mathbf{R}= \mathbf{r}$, while for the lattice constant $\alpha\mapsto \lambda \alpha $ holds.
That makes sense to me. What confuses me is section 12.6, where he derives the scaling fields, ie the fields which scale according to power laws near critical points under the scaling renormalization transformation. There he says (in page 261, just above equation 12.42a) that the scaling fields behave like that under the renormalization transformation in which distances transform according to $\mathbf{r}\mapsto\mathbf{R}= \mathbf{r}/\lambda$. I don't understand this. Doesn't this go against what he said about the distances not changing? It seems to me like he's quietly redefined his renormalization scheme some way that I don't quite get.
My goal here is to eventually understand what all that has to do with conformal invariance. I sort of get it but it is still confusing to me how exactly to define these scaling transformations in the context of lattice models.
